# Counting headset button clicks in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

Inside of the `onReceive(Content context, Intent intent)` method of my `public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver` I need to count the number of headset button clicks (single, double, triple), which is denoted by `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` of the `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON`.

What I have almost works, but my current algorithm sucks and is unreliable after a few times. Basically every successive `ACTION_DOWN` (hit within a certain number of milliseconds to the previous `ACTION_DOWN`) I do `numClicks++`. But also I need to see when the user is done pressing, so after each event I start a `CountDownTimer`, and if by the time it runs out there are no new clicks, then I'm done and now know the number of clicks.

The problems I'm running into are as follows: for one, the button itself seems noisy - if I press it too fast I usually miss a click. Two, after a few trials when the app it loaded, it starts getting random and I'm assuming that there are multiple `CountDownTimer` threads (is that the right word?) still running which screws my stuff up.

Anyways here's the main code snippet:

//note: `thisClickTime` uses `System.currentTimeMillis()`

```
   if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (isDown == true) {
            if (numClicks == 0 && lastClickTime == 0) {
                //we have a new click
                numClicks++;
                lastClickTime = thisClickTime; //update the click time
                isDown = false;
                elapsedTime = thisClickTime - lastClickTime;    
            } else if (thisClickTime - lastClickTime < clickDelay) { //&& thisClickTime - lastClickTime > 10
                numClicks++;
                lastClickTime = thisClickTime; 
                isDown = false; 
            }

            final int oldNumClicks = numClicks;
            final CountDownTimer checkIfDone = new CountDownTimer(clickDelay, 10) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (oldNumClicks != numClicks) {
                    cancel(); 
                }
            }
            public void onFinish() { //code that executes when counter is done
                if (oldNumClicks == numClicks) {
                    //if user doesn't click anymore in time clickDelay + X milliseconds, then it's done
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Number of clicks: " + Integer.toString(numClicks), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //reset state variables 
                    numClicks = 0;
                    lastClickTime = 0; 
                }
            }
           }.start();

        } else {
            //? 
        }
    }
```

For reference, I've been looking around at stuff like:

http://musicqueueproject.googlecode.com/svn-history/r83/trunk/src/com/yannickstucki/android/musicqueue/old/PlayerService.java

To see if there's a good way to register number of clicks. I don't really understand their code too well though, and from what I can see they only deal with single/double clicks (I may need triple and quadruple).

EDIT - uploaded the current code I'm working with. It works pretty decently most of the time. Here's what I've noticed though: if I do my button testing too close together in time, the results start screwing up and under counting the clicks. I think this is because other CountDownTimers from previous attempts are still open, and when they finish, they reset certain state variables (numClicks = 0, for one). So am I misusing the timer? I can't think of another solution though as I need some concept of elapsed time after the last click to determine when the clicking is done.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you solved this one? If so, please, share the code.

Comment: This was a long time ago, but yes I did solve it somehow. The general gist of what I did was to use threads that waited on each other to do sequential counting, only listening for a certain time period. It worked like this: upon the first click, start a new thread that listens for the next click; increase global click counter. If no other click happens in TIME_PERIOD time, exit the thread and use num_clicks = 1. Else, upon new click, spawn a new thread to listen... I'm sure that's not a good explanation. I'll try looking up my code later tonight/tomorrow and say what I did. But I did solve it!

Comment: Thank you. Nevertheless, it would be great if you share the code for the other users like, cause I'm new to android and unable to work with threads and etc well. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah the code is old, long, and crappy but here's what it does. I have a class extending BroadcastReceiver that listens for KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN (i.e. they pressed down on the button). Then I start a service class, clickService (extending Service, which is a background worker basically). The service does clickCount++ (a global), and then creates a RUNNABLE which does this: if oldNumClicks==clickCount, we're done and we have the # of clicks, else return. THE TRICK is to call handler.postDelayed(RUNNABLE, delay_allowed_between_clicks). 


That summarizes what I did =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `BroadcastReceiver` is registered in the manifest, the `BroadcastReceiver` will only exist for a single call to `onReceive()` -- subsequent broadcasts may result in another `BroadcastReceiver` instance. And a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` cannot fork threads, as the whole process may get shut down once `onReceive()` is over.

I am skeptical that there a clean way to get your code to be reliable, as the media button simply was not designed for your intended use pattern.

Comment: OK well I'm pretty flexible here - I just need a reliable way to determine how many headset button clicks someone does. The broadcastreceiver is registered in Java code using IntentFilter (in my mainActivity.java), and the class MediaButtonIntentReceiver is its own file (.java). Right now the counting is working fairly reliably IF I wait until the previous toast just about finished before trying more clicks. 

So what I think is happening is the CountDownTimer is screwing me up because multiple timers get started and when they finish they reset my state variables (numClicks = 0, etc).

Comment: @user624869: If the `MediaButtonIntentReceiver` is being registered by an `Activity`, I'd use `postDelayed()` for your "wake me up again in a bit" logic. That `Runnable` and `onReceive()` are both processed on the main application thread, so you don't have to worry about thread safety.